# Passing a foreign key via a form to a different controller without mass assignment security risks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am concerned about security of my implementation of a feature in my rails app.

I have two models, Assessments & AssessmentAttempts.

The Assessments show view displays a form (it's a multiple choice test form) but the data is sent to the AssessmentAttempts controller rather than to Assessments, which records the user_id, assessment_id and the user's choice on the test.

The current user's ID is not submitted as a part of the form, but currently I am submitting the assessment_id as a hidden field (taken from the URL e.g. /assessments/1).

This should not be modified: users should not be able to change that value or their choice will be associated with a different test question.

Is there a better way to get that assessment_id into the AssessmentAttempts controller than using a hidden field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an initial entry for the AssessmentAttempt in the database.  Give the AssessmentAttempt a unique token column and use that to validate the user's test as the hidden field in the form.

example:

```
token = SecureRandom.base64.tr("+/", "-_")
```

The good news: you have a history of incomplete attempts and some extra cross-site protection

The bad news: empty rows in your database.